# problema com if e else

Tags: java, string

eu estava no meio de uma aula de java e meu eclipse ide simplesmente não reconhece nenhum, IF
eu to a muito tempo tentando resolver alguém me ajuda

---

codigo:

```
package projeto_leitura;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
        String nome;
        Random rand = new Random();
        System.out.println("seja bem-vindo ao jogo! digite seu nome:");
        nome = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("seja muito bem vindo "+nome);
        System.out.println("voce deseja avançar para qual lado? w, a, s, d");
        String ff = in.nextLine();
        if(ff == "w") {
            System.out.println("você esta indo para frente");
            System.out.println("um inimigo apareceu o que fazer? w= atacar c=correr");
            ff = in.nextLine();
            if(ff == "w") {
                if(rand.nextInt(100) < 75) {
                    System.out.println("voce ganhou phorra");
                    
                }else {
                    System.out.println("você perdeu o jogo...");
                }
                
            }else {
                System.out.println("você correu o jogo acabou!");
            }
            }
            
        }
        
                
        
        

                                    
        
        

    

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Talvez utilizando o .equals() funcione.

```
if(ff.equals("w")) {
        System.out.println("você esta indo para frente");
        System.out.println("um inimigo apareceu o que fazer? w= atacar c=correr");
        ff = in.nextLine();....
```

Comment: krl mano ajudou demais obrigado!